# WCAG Questions about a web page issuing erorrs if cookies are disabled

Tags: accessibility

I have a question regarding the web content accessibility guidelines.

I have been asked to review whether a web application respects the WCAG 2.0 AA web standard.

I have to indicate the criteria that are in error, with suggestions on how to correct them.

In the application, there is a page that requires cookies to work properly. If the user has disabled cookies, there is a generic error message that appears.

> ## Error occurred
>
> Internal error occurred while processing your request.
>
> Please try again later.

In my opinion, this would fail on the criterion

[3.3.2 Labels or Instructions](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/minimize-error-cues.html)

> The intent of this Success Criterion is to help users avoid making
> mistakes when their input is required. To help avoid mistakes it is
> good user interface design to provide **simple instructions and cues** for
> entering information. Some users with disabilities may be more likely
> to make mistakes than users without disabilities or recovery from
> mistakes may be more difficult, making mistake avoidance an important
> strategy for users with disabilities. **People with disabilities rely on
> well documented forms and procedures to interact with a page**. Blind
> users need to know exactly what information should be entered into
> form fields and what the available choices are. Simple instructions
> visually connected to form controls can assist users with cognitive
> disabilities or those accessing a page using a screen magnifier.
>
> The intent of this Success Criterion is not to clutter the page with
> unnecessary information but to provide important cues and instructions
> that will benefit people with disabilities. Too much information or
> instruction can be just as much of a hindrance as too little. The goal
> is to make certain that enough information is provided for the user to
> accomplish the task **without undue confusion or navigation**.

However, some elements of the criterion seem to be focusing on user input.

I think this would also fail the [3.3.3 Error Suggestion](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/minimize-error-suggestions.html) criterion since there is an error and possible solutions are known.

However, 3.3.3 also seems to be focusing on user input.

This could also be a user experience issue that falls beyond the scope of what I was asked, but should I mark those criteria as failed ?

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, 3.3.2 and 3.3.3 are for [input errors](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#input-errordef) only. So they don't apply to your error message.

I didn't find any WCAG 2 guideline that would be directly related to non-`form` error messages (like error 403/404/…, "JS required", "Cookies required" etc.).

However, **if** the site makes a [conformance claim](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#conformance-claims), it needs to mention that cookies are [relied upon](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#reliedupondef) (some may argue that cookies are not a "[technology](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#technologydef)", though).

Despite WCAG not mentioning it, I think this error message is bad, not only for accessibility, but for usability reasons, too. The first thing: It doesn't tell *why* something went wrong. And even worse: It suggests to try again later. So users get the impression that the server has temporary problems, and they might try again, again and again.

Comment: I agree with you that it is a usability error. The site does not make an explicit conformance claim, but this is for a government system and it is **required** that it meets the WCAG guidelines.

Comment: So, I'd say according to WCAG 2 AA there is no problem. You don't *need* a conformance claim, and you don't have to follow any special rules for such error messages.

Comment: I ended up writing something like : **Usability note**:
Even if this does not fall under any of the WCAG 2.0 AA criterion,  the following error should be corrected:
When clicking on one of the buttons with cookies disabled, you are sent to an error page with no help indicating what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would. It's a pretty serious oversight not to have meaningful errors outside of WCAG, and it certainly makes things easier for your disabled users.